# Assert on Flux List which changes list contents while iterating

Tags: junit, java-8, mockito, reactive, flux

I am having a flux created from list of object type. While iterating on List I am calling 2 methods updateCashCT and updatePaymentDocument for which item of list which updates the list items. Since I am making change in list object itself I am not returning list object from this method , How to assert on changed list object using junit ?

```
    Flux.fromIterable(chargeTransactionListForOrder)
    .filter(ct -> PaymentTypes.CASH.name().equalsIgnoreCase(ct.getPaymentType()))
    .doOnNext(ct -> updateCashCT(ct)).doOnNext(ct -> updatePaymentDocument(ct, payment))
    .blockLast();
```